# ReactJS Error - "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" after implementing absolute imports

Tags: reactjs, import, typeerror

I have the following code:

App.js

```
...
import {sortData, prettyPrintStat} from 'util/util';
...
<div className="app__stats">
<InfoBox 
  isRed
  active={casesType === 'cases'}
  onClick={e => setCasesType('cases')}
  title="Cases" 
  cases={prettyPrintStat(countryInfo.todayCases)} 
  total={prettyPrintStat(countryInfo.cases)}/>
...
```

util.js

```
...
export const sortData = (data) => {
    const sortedData = [...data];
    sortedData.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.cases > b.cases) {
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            return 1
        }
    });
    return sortedData;
};
export const prettyPrintStat = (stat) => {
    return stat ? `+${numeral(stat).format("0.0a")}` : "+0"
};
...
```

For absolute import I have implemented the jsconfig file as follows

jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./src"
    }
}
```

While running this I get an error saying

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

Attaching a screenshot of the error.
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCymj.png)

I tried some solutions from the web like updating React and React-DOM to the latest versions. Also tried deleting the node_modules folder and re-installing. None of them seem to be of any help.

However if I remove the absolute imports implementation and use the below code, everything seems to work fine

App.js

```
...
import {sortData, prettyPrintStat} from './util/util';
...
```

Can anyone please help me figure out what's going wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: as mentioned [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports) in the docs for create-react-app, syntax for  baseUrl should be ```baseUrl: "src"```
also there is an ```include: ['src']``` key at the end of this object.

Comment: @humanbean Thank you for the response. I tried the same thing from the documentation, but the error still exists.

Comment: maybe [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) one has more verbose documentation on the usage of jsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by renaming my util file to helper.js

For example,

```
import { prettyPrintStat, sortData } from 'util/helper'
```

instead of

```
import { prettyPrintStat, sortData } from 'util/util'
```